# How would I be able to make a button that retrieves a Quote Object from it's current page, and then send it to another page?

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

Title basically explains my question, I need to make a button that retrieves the Quote Object from one page and then send it to another VisualForce page that is rendered as a pdf and allows a user to print out all the info. Any idea as to how I would create this button and how i would allow it to send the data from one page to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the button to grab a quote object from the page, grab the ID of the quote in the action method, return a pagereference going to the second page while passing the ID in the query string.

return new PageReference('/apex/mypdfpage?id='+myQuote.ID);

then on the myPDF page, extract the quote details using SOQL and render accordingly :)

Comment: This is really helpful, but I just have two questions:                                                         1.) would the button be a javascript button and 2.) I know how to use a query but i'm not sure how to search for a button that was clicked

Comment: Would you rather go for a javascript approach or the non-javascript approach? :)

Comment: whatever way is most efficient :)

Comment: Get the Quote ID of the object that you want to get displayed on your pdf page, lets say its going to be myQuote.ID.


Create a pagereference that returns "return new PageReference('/apex/mypdfpage?id='+myQuote.ID);" - lets call the method public PageReference pdfMe()


place pdfMe() in the apex:buttoncommand that you have. <apex:commandButton action="{!pdfMe}" />


and there you go!

Comment: if I have a preexisting page would it be PageReference myPDF = Page.(PDFQuoteTemplate+?id=quote.id); or am i off? If you would like to see me code for anything i can include it

Comment: well that would work, just pass to the page reference the URL to your page plus the ID in the querystring :)

Comment: I am really lost i've used a query string for an object on the page but I have no idea how to apply it to the new page.

Comment: Actually I understand this, but how do i add the id to the pdf page? I tried adding id="{!Quote.QuoteNumber}" in the <apex:page> but it says it can't do that since Quote isnt an actual object yet

Comment: on your other page (assuming that it uses a quote standardcontroller) create an extension. in your extension place something like this public Extension_Class(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.myQuote = (Quote)controller.getRecord();
        myQuote = [SELECT id, field1, field2 FROM Quote WHERE id = :myQuote.id];} -- make sure to have an instance variable: public Quote myQuote {get;set;}

Comment: Should the ?id= part of the url just generate than?

Comment: So i get an error and I'm pretty sure it's because I use a button to get to the page and since the button isn't associated with the QuoteNumber there is nothing for it to grab so it just ends up coming up as an error, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: hmm well basically this will be the logic ON PAGE 1= get your quote object, extract the ID, put the ID in the URL, use that to get to page 2. ON PAGE 2 = use the ID you got from page 1, query the values, save it to a variable accessible on your page and display it. does this explain it better? :)

Comment: It explains it very well, but i dont know how i would get page 2's URL to be dynamic. also sorry for the long wait i tend to stay away from work on weekends

Comment: I figured out the first part by making the action of the button = "/apex/pdfpage?id={!var.QuoteNumber}". The problem i have now is when i try to make the id of the pdf page={!Quote.QuoteNumber}, i get an error saying it needs a literal value, any help?

Comment: try accessing your page with a quote number from your sandbox/org and see how it'll react.

Comment: I got the same error :( is it because I am using a standard controller? Should i just make a controller to replace the standard and extension controllers?

Comment: I just used Apex.Pages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',myQuote.QuoteNumber); myQuote is a public variableon the extended method. Instead of getting the old error, I now get an error that says "Id value is not valid for the Quote standard controller ". This is progress I think lol also thank you for all your help so far @dotmiko

Comment: you're welcome! :) but just fyi, try passing myQuote.ID instead of QuoteNumber. I think that should work :)

Comment: omg it worked! thank you so much!!! i would upvote everything if i could :)

Comment: no biggie! i'm glad to help :)